# Insert value in relational table

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tables:

1. Board(BID(PK), BoardName, date, Status)
2. Medium(MID(PK), MediumName, Date, status)
3. BoardMedium(BMID(PK), BID(FK), MID(FK))

above is my table structre .I wanted to Take Name Of Board and name of medium from dropdown(already filled) and insert into BoardMedium table only BID and MID.user will provide Boardname and Mediumname based on these two value i have to check wheather it is available in BoardMedium table or not if not then insert into BoardMedium table only BID and MID.can any on help me to achieve the same .Thanks in advance...

Comment: You seem to know what you need to do - what have you tried? If you tried nothing, can you explain why not?

Comment: oded can u give me an idea how to achieve that, i don't want exact code for that , at-least u can give me a direction to do that.hope u don't mind.thanks

Comment: But what did you try? What direction did you go with? What database access technology did you use? We have a general expectation here that someone who asks a question made an effort - you have not shown in your question any such thing.

Comment: oded thanks..i'l do it..